# Laravel withTrashed how to return whole DB result?

Tags: php, laravel

```
$query->whereIn('status', $status)->withTrashed();
```

Ok i want to get rows where statuses are as defined PLUS trashed rows. So, not rows with given status and trashed, but rows with status AND those trashed ones.
How to accomplish this in Laravel? Two queries? How?

Answer (score 1):

You can do an extra check to see if the `deleted_at` column is empty, asuming this is the column you use for trashed rows.

```
$query->withTrashed()->whereIn('status', $status)->orWhereNotNull('deleted_at')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following;

```
$query->withTrashed()->whereIn('status', $status)->get();
```

Comment: same, getting those which satisfy both conditions

Comment: Can you paste the output of $query->withTrashed()->whereIn('status', $status)->toSql();